# Powershell objects assigning values to object on the 'right side' of 'equal character'

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-ise

I have a powershell script running steps such as

```
$stuffFromAPI = $resultsFromAPI.inputs.Stuff | ConvertFrom-Json
$objectFromAPIStuff = $stuffFromAPI.item[0] #ipAddress = 127.0.0.1 
$newStuff = @()
$tempStuff = $null
$condition = "yup"
$IPAddress = "10.0.0.1"
if($condtion -eq "yup")
{
    $tempStuff = $objectFromAPIStuff
    $tempStuff.ipAddress = $IPAddress
    $newBindings+=$tempStuff
}

Write-Host $tempStuff.ipAddress
Write-Host $objectFromAPIStuff.ipAddress
Write-Host $stuffFromAPI.item[0].ipAddress
```

The output will be

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
```

why is `$objectFromAPIStuff` and even deeper `$stuffFromAPI.item[0]` inheriting the changed values of `$tempStuff`

There seems to be some link between them in memory. I have closed powershell ISE and reopened it, and I have even restarted my computer thinking something was just cached weird in powershell ISE

Comment: This is expected behavior. `$tempStuff`, `$objectFromAPIStuff` and `$stuffFromAPI.item[0]` all contain a reference to the same object in memory

Comment: How do I separate them so I can edit them individually?

Comment: The linked duplicate discusses the underlying concepts as well as (invariably limited) options for cloning objects (making independent copies).